# Is there a power of $x$ for which the digits can be rearranged to get a different power of $x$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am wondering, is there a power of $x$ for which the digits can be rearranged to get a different power of $x$, where $x$ is an integer greater than $1$? Obviously, $x<10$. If $x$ is not divisible by $3$, then there is no such power (proof like [here](https://orion.math.iastate.edu/ehjohnst/PoW/Sp2009/Soln13(4-13-09).pdf)).

Comment: "Obviously, x<10" why on earth is that obvious?  In fact I'd think the result is more likely if we allow for more options.

Comment: @fleablood if $x>10$ then $a*x$ has more digit than $a$ so you can not really rearrange digit to make $a$.

Comment: But it can be true if you allow yourself to put $0$ in front of your number but I do not think OP allow this. In this case $10$ is working since $10^2=100$ which you can rearrange as $010=10^1$.

Comment: Oh.... Oddly enough that thought never occurred to me... (it was late?)...  But this also means that if $x^k > x^m$ have the same digits then $x^{k-m}<10$ and $k-m < \log_x 10 =\frac 1{\log_{10} x}$.